# Getting error while using xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink in Manjaro after update

Tags: manjaro, intel-graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics, skylake

I am using Manjaro KDE edition. I have a system with Skylake i5 processor and hybrid graphics.

```
System:    Host: aditya-laptop Kernel: 4.4.8-1-MANJARO x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.3.0)
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.6.3 (Qt 5.6.0) Distro: Manjaro Linux
Machine:   System: HP product: HP Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId
           Mobo: HP model: 8136 v: 31.36 Bios: Insyde v: F.1F date: 01/18/2016
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-6200U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9603
           clock speeds: max: 2800 MHz 1: 699 MHz 2: 2694 MHz 3: 750 MHz 4: 750 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330]
           bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.17.4 drivers: ati,radeon,intel     Resolution: 1920x1080@60.06hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.1 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

With an earlier version of kernel 4.4 as well as drivers, PRIME offloading worked properly with the commands `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink radeon Intel`

However now after updating the kernel and xf86 drivers, it does not work.

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x66 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x0 crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:HAINAN @ pci:0000:01:00.0
$ xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink  0x3f 0x66
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 (RRSetProviderOffloadSink)
  Value in failed request:  0x3f
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

I don't know where exactly the problem is as many packages got updated, which includes the kernel as well as `xf86-video-intel` and `xf86-video-ati` packages. I have also installed the linux4.6 kernel but I get the same problem on that too.

Comment: I have the exact same error, except this is not a radeon card: this a nvidia geforce. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug that got fixed with the next release of the kernels.

If someone has to use the affected kernel, they can use the `radeon.nopm=0` kernel boot time option which is a workaround.

The related bug report [here on freedesktop](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94874).